# Inheritance of templated methods

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a question about inheritance and template methods. Suppose I have this two classes

```
class Base
{
public:
   template<typename T>
   void print(const T& s) {std::cout << "Base (templated) prints " << s << "\n";}
   virtual void print(int i) {std::cout << "Base prints " << i << "\n";}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   void print(int i) {std::cout << "Derived prints " << i << "\n";}
}

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   d.print(3);     // works fine
   std::string s = "hi";
   d.print(s);  // does not compile
   return 0;
}
```

The compiler tells me ''no matching function for call to ‘Derived::print(std::string&)’'.
But Derived, inheriting from Base, should also allow a call to the template method print(..), no?

Things are also weird cause if I don't define a method "print" in the derived class, then everything works fine and the compiler calls the base class template method.

Things work fine also if I define the template method also in the derived class, which calls the base class one, but that does not seem right to me...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Alright, I edited the question cause there were some particular I left out. I was trying to simplify the question but I might have left out important details (like the virtual function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a function in the derived class hides any functions with the same name in the base class. You can unhide them with a using declaration:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // Add this
    using Base::print;

    void print(int i) {std::cout << "Derived prints " << i << "\n";}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought that since one of the two was templated and the other not, they would have not been considered the same. Also because the Base class has a method (not templated) that perfectly matches the derived one as signature. So I though the Derived one hided only that one.

(I edited the question to include also the non templated version in the base classe).

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard base name hide, and has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the fact that the base class function is a template. It could be the second coming of Jesus and the compiler would still hide it. It's normal behaviour, implemented to try and protect derived classes from unexpected changes in base classes.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I though I couldn't hide the template method...I just thought it was different...